# Plotting categorical variable using 2 other categorical variables as row and column in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot Loan Status using row as Gender and column as Self Employed.

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(train,row='Gender',col='Self_Employed',size=2.2,aspect=1.6)
g.map(plt.hist,'Loan_Status')
g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Error is - 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to `Loan_Status` containing at least one string.

See the following example.

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['Male','Female','Male','Female']*3,
                      'Self_Employed':['Yes','Yes','No']*4,'Somevalue':[1,2,3,4]*3, 'String':['yes','No','No']*4})

g=sns.FacetGrid(train,row='Gender',col='Self_Employed',size=2.2,aspect=1.6)
g.map(plt.hist,'Somevalue')
g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Results in this image.

[image]

Whereas when we try to do the same with `String` which is comprised solely of strings.

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(train,row='Gender',col='Self_Employed',size=2.2,aspect=1.6)
g.map(plt.hist,'String')
g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

I get the same error you are getting.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

To resolve your issue you must check your `Loan_Status` column and encode your strings (which I presume are labels) to numbers. You can take a look at the sklearn [label encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to do this for you. Or write some code yourself to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks.I did the same later on by changing Y into 1 and N into 0. Hence, the probelm was solved.

Comment: If this was the solution to your question please accept the answer. So  it is clear there is a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Yeah this is the solution as I tried plotting using different columns and got the result.The only problem was that it was a string.

Comment: Then I would say either accept this answer or post your solution and accept that as answer.